# Does it holds that $A - \epsilon B \succeq 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A, B$ be two equal-sized, symmetric matrices with $A,B \succeq 0$, and let $\epsilon > 0$. I am conjecturing that:  $$A - \epsilon B \succeq 0 \quad\text{as}\quad \epsilon \to 0$$ if (i) $rank (A) \ge rank(B)$, and
(ii) all diagonal entries of $A>0$.

My question is whether my conjecture is true and, if yes, how to prove it.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: The question is whether the above holds for small but positive $\epsilon$; i.e., whether there exists some $\bar\epsilon$ such that the condition holds for all $0 < \epsilon < \bar \epsilon$

Comment: I don't understand your conjecture.  What does $A - \epsilon B \succeq 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ mean, and how is it distinct from $A \succeq 0$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, It seem to me, the things mentioned here concern to close to $A$ matrices, and not to exactly $A$. The conjectured thing is that close to $A$ matrices are also non-negative -definite, if they are of the form above, with the conditions satisfied.

Comment: One question to clear all up. What if I take exactly positive-definite matrix. Is this case solved?

Comment: @kolobokish if $A$ is positive definite, then the statement holds.  In particular, the positive definite matrices form the interior of the cone of positive semidefinite matrices, within the space of symmetric matrices

Comment: Yes, the clarification of kolobokish is indeed the one I had in mind. I'll edit to make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture, if I understand it correctly, is false. Take
$$
A = \frac 12 \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}, \quad 
B = \pmatrix{1 &0\\0&0}
$$
verify that for all $\epsilon > 0$: $\det(A - \epsilon B) < 0$.

Comment: Thanks, your interpretation was indeed the one I had in mind and the example proves my conjecture wrong.

Comment: One quick follow-up question: Does someone have an idea how one could refine my original conjecture so that $A - \epsilon B$ holds for small but positive $\epsilon$. The trivial case of $A$ being strictly positive-definite that was mentioned above is not an option here). I guess $A$ needs to be "similar" to $B$ in some way, but I don't have a good idea which type of similarity that would need to be

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you need is $\ker(A) \subset \ker(B)$.  I know it's sufficient, but I don't know if it's necessary. An equivalent condition to this one (since our matrices are symmetric) is $im(B) \subset im(A)$